# How to display users location on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For my chrome extension I am trying to display users location. My js code is as below

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(loc){
    var x = document.getElementById(demo);
    getLocation();


});
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

And added permission in mainfest.json

```
"permissions": [
"tabs", "<all_urls>",
"geolocation"
```

]

But it is not displaying anything. please advice me.

Comment: Have you accept chrome for accessing your current location?

Comment: Above code works fine for me.

Comment: can you please tell how to accept chrome to access location?

Comment: Just click the button and it will auto ask permission on request.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

You just have to allow your chrome to access your location.

Comment: I referred same site. how to allow chrome to access location?

Comment: When you click the button what happens?

Comment: Pls. check http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Location-Services-on-Google-Chrome

Comment: Thanks. Done with chrome setting. But now it is showing 'Uncaught Reference Error: x is not defined at showPosition' this error message when i inspect the pop up.

Comment: Is that on w3school?